# React + json output in chart

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a simple json file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bitcoin",
  "quantity": 1,
  "price": 1,
  "old_price": 0.99,
  "info": "The most famous one",
  "archived_data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "jan",
      "sold": 5,
      "bought": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "feb",
      "sold": 15,
      "bought": 30
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "mar",
      "sold": 5,
      "bought": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "apr",
      "sold": 15,
      "bought": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

I now want to display them in my chart:

```
import CanvasJSReact from '../plugins/canvasjs.react';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

class CryptoChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.toggleDataSeries = this.toggleDataSeries.bind(this);
    }

    toggleDataSeries(e){
        e.dataSeries.visible = !(typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible);
        this.chart.render();
    }

    render() {
        const options = {
            theme: "light2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisX: {
                title: "Months"
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Sold",
                titleFontColor: "#007bff",
                lineColor: "#007bff",
                labelFontColor: "#007bff",
                tickColor: "#007bff"
            },
            axisY2: {
                title: "Bought",
                titleFontColor: "#51CDA0",
                lineColor: "#51CDA0",
                labelFontColor: "#51CDA0",
                tickColor: "#51CDA0"
            },
            toolTip: {
                shared: true
            },
            legend: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                itemclick: this.toggleDataSeries
            },
            data: [
                {
                    type: "spline",
                    name: "Sold",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    xValueFormatString: "MMM YYYY",
                    yValueFormatString: "#,##0 Units",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: new Date(2020, 0, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[0].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 1, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[1].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 2, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[2].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 3, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[3].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 4, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[4].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 5, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[5].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 6, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[6].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 7, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[7].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 8, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[8].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 9, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[9].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 10, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[10].sold },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 11, 1), y: this.props.crypto.quantity}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    type: "spline",
                    name: "Bought",
                    axisYType: "secondary",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    xValueFormatString: "MMM YYYY",
                    yValueFormatString: "$#,##0.#",
                    dataPoints: [
                        { x: new Date(2020, 0, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[0].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 1, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[1].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 2, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[2].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 3, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[3].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 4, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[4].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 5, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[5].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 6, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[6].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 7, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[7].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 8, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[8].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 9, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[9].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 10, 1), y: this.props.crypto.archived_data[10].bought },
                        { x: new Date(2020, 11, 1), y: this.props.crypto.quantity }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <CanvasJSChart options = {options} onRef={ref => this.chart = ref} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}  export default CryptoChart;
```

The `this.props.crypto.quantity` works as expected, but the `this.props.crypto.archived_data[0].sold` and `this.props.crypto.archived_data[0].bought` don't work: the app crashes and the console says

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Does anyone know how to output this?

Edit: Ive made a react.new [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dijkstra-8h8zj?file=/src/App.js) so its easier to see what is going wrong and maybe how it can be fixed

Comment: `console.log(this.props.crypto.archived_data)` what does this show?

Comment: It means your are not getting a populated list for your archived_data property.

Comment: console.log(this.props.crypto.archived_data) gives undefined